# Front office not loading, back office fine, error 524, 500 & mysql too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, centos, prestashop, kloxo

I already been searched everywhere, I won't to start a solved topic again. First of all I want to say thanks for going to read my poor English  :)

My problem is My front office not working sometimes it shows ***error 500***, sometimes shows mysql error too many connections and most of the times it shows ***error 524*** by cloudflare.

But interesting thing is when it's on maintenance, that's mean I'm disabling the shop then it showing well, which is shop is on under maintenance, will be back soon.

When I enable the shop then suffering to visit back office also and when I use the command `sh /script/restart-all` then back office is well as before.

I'm facing this problem from 3 days when I moved my website from a old hosting to new hosting (both control panel is kloxo 7, server was vps now dedicated) searched everywhere as possible as but nothing is working.

Already I've done

- `.htaccess deleted,`
- `sh /script/fix-all`, `restart`, `clean-all`,
- installed kloxo 3/4 times properly

Configuration

- Using Prestashop 1.6.1.7
- mysql mariaDB-myisam
- CentOS 6
- Kloxo 7

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Without code, it's hard to be sure. Check your error logs for why the error 500 is occurring. For too many connections, check your mysql settings, check your queries, and make sure you're not using persistent connections. Look at mysql's error and slow query logs, if they're turned on. If not, turn them on.

Comment: sound like you arent closing the connections after use it. but is very hard to  guess.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i didn't really understand what i've to do :( anyone would like to tell me step by step what i've to do, Thanks

Comment: i would like to provide my php, mysql and full server credentials what you need, website www.buymebrand.com

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, 
after ssh login i used command

```
sh /script/fix-all
sh /script/restart-all
```

and everything works fine